# API Platform Custom Filter With Between Issue

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I created a custom filter where it filters the range of the total (e.g. items) with their status of delivered. I'm using the `SIZE` but unfortunately, it only filters the actual total items not the `SIZE` of the items with status of delivered. For some reason, there's a problem with the `'SIZE(' . $alias . '.items) BETWEEN :from AND :to'` because the `BETWEEN` is filtering all of the items, not the filtered items.

Here's my full code:

```
protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        if ($property !== 'totalDeliveredItems' || empty($value)) {
            return;
        }

        $alias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];

        $queryBuilder
           ->innerJoin($alias . '.items', 'item')
           ->andWhere(
                'SIZE(' . $alias . '.items) BETWEEN :from AND :to'
           )
          ->andWhere('item.status = :status')
          ->setParameter('status', 'delivered')
          ->setParameter('from', 1)
          ->setParameter('to', 20);

        $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I tried asking ChatGPT but no success. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to inspect the generated query? Symfony's Profiler can help you do that

Comment: I tried using dump and die, the SIZE filter works on the total items, not on the total delivered items

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Sounds like the filter itself is not applied?

Comment: Try using the symfony profile and provide what the query string is for the database

Comment: While there might a better way to do it, the first thing that comes to mind is to reverse the query -- that is to query from the item side